# How to place picture after table in Display Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, display-form, picture

I work with SharePoint Online. 
I have Display Form of my list of Employees like this: 
[image]

I tried to use jQuery .insertAfter($(".ms-formtable")  or .appendTo()  methods, but result is only this: 
[image]

I neet to place this picture beside this table like this: [image]

Could somebody help me, please? I don't know what can I use and how. CSS or jQuery? How to place this picture beside, not after this .ms-formtable ???

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Danny'365CSI' Engelman, I found the solution: 
Picture attached to Item is #SPFieldURL 
I added this CSS code and it works:

```
  <style type="text/css"> 
#WebPartWPQ1{
position: relative;
}
.ms-formtoolbar {
display: none;
}
#SPFieldURL {
position: absolute;
bottom: 110px;
}  
</style>
```

There is result: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add HTML with jQuery and style it.

Or you can do it without any HTML and use CSS,
all you have to do then is get the CSS in that page
(*you will probably use jQuery coding to create that IMG url dynamically, since you can't generate the CSS server-side in SPOnline*)

```
<STYLE>
#WebPartWPQ1{
  position: relative;
}
#WebPartWPQ1::after{
  content: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/3/DEMO-CSS-ONLY/);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -200px;
}
</STYLE>
```

The `position:relative` is needed to make the next `position:absolute` be contained inside the DIV of the WebPart

You then attach and IMG `:after`the DIV and move it IMG-width pixels to the right

You can do this on the `.ms-formtable` as well, but SPOnline also displays a Recommendations DIV to the right of the `ms-formtable`, so your IMG will cover that then.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. What can I put insted "content: url(http://lorempixel.com/200/300/people/3/DEMO-CSS-ONLY/);" therefore my picture is changing with every item (item is information abou employee and pisture is his photo). Your URL is only for one picture,  isn't it?     And I don't understand to your next instructions about IMG:after. Could you describe this information much more, please?

Comment: That is why I said to create the STYLE and inject it into the page (like you would do with HTML) with jQuery. ::after is basic CSS: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp

Comment: That's great, I've got Demo picture on the right place, but how to change your STYLE code to do it with my picture of employee?

Comment: With jQuery or any other JavaScript code to generate the HTML (STYLE in this case) and inject it in the page... Best thing (requires serious programming skills) i to use SharePoint Client Side Rendering to convert a Picture Field into this STYLE code... Or ductape it with jQuery code reading a Picture Url from the current DisplayForm, create the STYLE and inject

Answer (score 1):

Here try to find the HTML element the picture is placed after that table , or you create a div and place this picture inside that and you need to apply some **css** to fix the position using **Left position** and **float** attributes . hope this will help.